# How to stream music from my playlist in soundcloud to my android app?

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

i had read some answers but they all had not  worked. I tried to stream music from my account on soundcloud to my andorid app
My code looks like this

In a class, i have:

> 1class.java

```
public static final String my_client_id = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
public static final String my_api_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com";
// I also tried with https, but it also still dont work. Where is the difference ?
//public static final String my_api_url = "https://api.soundcloud.com";
```

In an interface i have the following code

> test.java

```
@GET("/users/my_id_has_9numbers/tracks?client_id=" + Config.my_client_id)
//@GET("/users/my_username/tracks?client_id=" + Config.my_client_id)

public void getRecentTracks(@Query("created_at[from]") String date, Callback<List<Piste>> cb);
```

I use here the retrofit library. Then in another class

> MyClass.java

```
test.getRecentTracks(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()), new Callback<List<Piste>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Piste> pistes, Response response) {

                loadTracks(pistes);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error);
            }
        });

private void loadTracks(List<Piste> pistes) {
        list_of_items.clear();
        list_of_items.addAll(pistes);
        myAdapta.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

When i buid the code, and start the app, i dont see the tracks, the activity is blank.

I also used this url
public static final String API_URL = "https://api.soundcloud.com";

@GET("/tracks/119172754/stream?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID)

Please i hope you could help me. Thks

Comment: All the tracks are public